# How To count the number of rows in a Web Table with multiple pages In Selenium WebDriver?

Tags: rowcount

[image][Please check the attached image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EUbuq.png) How To count the number of rows in a Web Table with multiple pages In Selenium Web Driver? As per filter, the data displayed in a table with 15 rows on first page among 25 pages with 350 rows. I am not getting the total number of rows. Please help.

```
//To locate table.
WebElement mytable = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='list']"));
//To locate rows of table.
List<WebElement> rows_table = mytable.findElements(By.tagName("tr"));
//To calculate no of rows In table.
int rows_count = rows_table.size();
rows_count=rows_count-1;
//Loop will execute till the last row of table.
//for (int row=0; row<rows_count; row++)
System.out.println("Number Of Rows = "+rows_count);
}
```

Comment: Please add your image to this post. No one wants to open a link

Comment: I have added. Can you help me please...?